# Uploading acepted ACL paper to arXiv

Tags: publications, arxiv, preprint, license

I have written an accepted paper for the [2020 Annual Conference of the Association for Computational Linguistics (ACL)](https://acl2020.org/). While uploading the final version, I agreed to this copyright statement:

> Copyright to the above work (including, without limitation, the right
>   to publish the work in whole or in part in any and all forms and
>   media, now or hereafter known) is hereby transferred to the
>   Association for Computational Linguistics (ACL), effective as of the
>   date of this agreement, on the understanding that the work has been
>   accepted for presentation at a meeting sponsored by the ACL and for
>   publication in the proceedings of that meeting. However, each of the
>   authors and the employers for whom the work was performed reserve all
>   other rights, specifically including the following: (1) All
>   proprietary rights other than copyright and publication rights
>   transferred to ACL; (2) The right to publish in a journal or
>   collection or to be used in future works of the author's own (such as
>   articles or books) all or part of this work, provided that
>   acknowledgment is given to the ACL and a full citation to its
>   publication in the particular proceedings is included; (3) The right
>   to make oral presentation of the material in any forum; (4) The right
>   to make copies of the work for internal distribution within the
>   author's organization and for external distribution as a preprint,
>   reprint, technical report, or related class of document.

I would like to upload the same final paper to arXiv. Am I allowed to do so?

Specifically, I think exception (4) might be relevant here, as the proceedings aren't published yet, so I guess it would be a pre-print? However, it is the same final paper, not some intermediate result.

I am aware that uploading the accepted papers to arXiv is common practice. Many authors advertise this eg. on Twitter, so ACL must be aware of it. But do they just ignore it, or is it actually legal?

Comment: You appear to have answered your own question already. The copyright agreement seems clear enough to me that it *is* legal to publish preprints.

Comment: Ok, so a "preprint" is defined as "something before the official publication" and not as "a draft you had before getting the final paper that's eventually published"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While only they can say for sure, it is *probably* fine to do so, but you also probably need to include their copyright notice with the uploaded version.

But to be certain, ask them specifically for guidance.

It isn't a "preprint" as you note, but it is a "reprint" and probably falls under the "related" class of documents.